# Google Apps Script Change nth Row height in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to change the height of every 3rd row within a Google Sheet using Apps Script.

The commented out ***.setBackground()*** works as expected, however ***.SetRowHeight()*** throws up the following error:
**TypeError: sheet.getRange(...).autoResizeRows is not a function**

```
function Height() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var totalRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var totalColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns()

  for (var i=3; i <= totalRows; i+=3){
      //sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, totalColumns).setBackground("#F3F3F3");
      sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, totalColumns).setRowHeight(1, 200);
  }
}
```

Any assistance, gratefully received.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a dummy sheet file with sample data that looks similar to your actual project for replication purposes?

Comment: Is this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEfQF.gif) the expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setRowHeight is a method that works on a sheet, not range.

You can do it like this:

```
function Height() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var totalRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var totalColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns()

  for (var i=3; i <= totalRows; i+=3){
      //sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, totalColumns).setBackground("#F3F3F3");
      if (i%3 === 0) {
          sheet.setRowHeight(i, 200);
      }
  }
}
```